# how to detect errors in web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js

this is my code

```
for(var i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; i++){
myContract.methods.contractmanager(i).call().then((res)=>{
console.log(res[0]);
}):
}
```

there is 2 data stored in my contract and i want to print it but it is not always 2 and it will be more and dynamic and i wont know how many they will be. after executing this code i have 2 output and 2 error. how to make the loop stop at 2 and it wont show the errors? how to detect the error and break the loop? how to find out if the output is empty or not?
solidity code:

```
function contractmanager(uint i) public view returns(uint , address , address , uint , uint , uint){
            return (contrs[list_contr[i]].idc , contrs[list_contr[i]].seller , contrs[list_contr[i]].buyer, contrs[list_contr[i]].price ,contrs[list_contr[i]].date , contrs[list_contr[i]].pos );
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and share the `contractmanager()` Solidity function as well as its dependencies. This will allow us to better troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: done. but its nothing important. it just returns data

Comment: And the `list_contr[i]` and `contrs[list_contr[i]]` exist? What are their datatypes (e.g. a dynamic-length array, a mapping, ...)? ... Is it possible that you're trying to reach an undefined item of an array? (Example: The array has length 2, but you're trying to get index 3.)

Comment: its a dynamic array and i want to get data in javascript so i needed a for loop to get data. for example its length is 5 but my for loop continues till 50 i want to prints 5 array of data and detects that array is empty

Answer (score 0):

The EVM throws an exception when you're trying to access an item of an array with higher index than the array length. It's basically the same thing as "array index out of bounds" exception in other languages.

You'll need to create a separate function to get the array length (see `myArrayLength()` in the example below) and perform the length check in your JS code this way.

---

**Example:**

*Solidity*

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    uint256[] public myArray;
    
    function addToArray(uint256 _value) external {
        myArray.push(_value);
    }
    
    function myArrayLength() external view returns (uint256) {
        return myArray.length;
    }
}
```

*Node.js*

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const WEB3_PROVIDER = 'http://127.0.0.1:7545/';
const ABI_JSON = [{
    "inputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "_value", "type": "uint256"}],
    "name": "addToArray",
    "outputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
}, {
    "inputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}],
    "name": "myArray",
    "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
}, {
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "myArrayLength",
    "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
}];
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '0xCc0607EfdF166344fc94589a61F09dcFbC89B1a7';
const FROM_ADDRESS = '0x8553DA9C81f940041ee4F46c14e2C7b20ad32F8C';

const run = async () => {
    const web3 = new Web3(WEB3_PROVIDER);
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI_JSON, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

    await contract.methods.addToArray(123).send({from: FROM_ADDRESS}); // sets the first item

    const firstItem = await contract.methods.myArray(0).call(); // retrieves the item with index 0 (the existing, first item)
    console.log(firstItem);

    try {
        const otherItem = await contract.methods.myArray(100).call(); // tries to retrieve the item with index 100 (non-existing)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Failed");
    }

    const length = await contract.methods.myArrayLength().call();
    console.log(length);
}

run();
```

*Console output*

```
123
Failed
1
```

Comment: thx for your answer but here is my main problem: "catch" does not get the error and does not print the "failed" message in console it just logging the error

Comment: I have the same issue, if there is an error from the contract method called (like a require()), the catch is not triggered

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ".catch()" method like in the following code :

```
async function getBlockInfo(i) {
    await web3.eth.getBlock(i).then(block => {
        block.transactions.forEach(function (t) {
            web3.eth.getTransaction(t).then(transaction => {
                console.log(i + ' ' + transaction.hash + ' ' + transaction.from + ' ' + transaction.to)
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('erreur')
            })
        })
    }).catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
}
```